# JsRender if statement support

Tags: if-statement, jsrender

Does jsRender supports if statments like below ?

```
{{ if val > 1  }}
....
{{ /if }}
```

I couldn't find any examples.
Also I understand that there is a variant of using helper functions.

Comment: http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2011/10/21/Using-simple-conditional-logic-in-JsRender

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, see [www.jsviews.com/#iftag](http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag).

In fact you can write `{{if pathOrExpr}}` where path can be any combination of 'data paths' and reqular javascript operators etc.

The example shows `{{if members && members.length}}` and similarly you can do all the expected conditional expressions such as:

`address.zip === '88888'`, or:

`foo.count < 3 && foo.total >= bar.total`,

etc. etc.